# How to auto import NestJS decorator?

Tags: node.js, nestjs

i'm getting tired of adding decorator (like @Req, @Res, @Param,... ) by hand. I used vscode hint (Ctrl+Space) but it didnt show exact decorator from from @nestjs/common. Please help?

I used vscode hint (Ctrl+Space) but it didnt show exact decorator from from @nestjs/common

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why this happend but when i restart VScode, it fixed!